# edit the price without clicking text field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento

we are using magento marketplace site.

we are using following code to update the price.

Now we have to click on the Textfield to edit the price.

but what we need is without clicking on the textfield it should be editable.

Means once we click on the text field ,than only its allowing to edit.

but without clicking on the textfield it should be editable.

**Php**

```
    <span class="label pro_status">
        <?php //echo $products->getPrice(); ?>                              

        <span class = "ama1"  id="valueprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>"
        onclick="showFieldPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>');"><?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?></span>


        <input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "price_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" "name = "price" value = "<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" style = "display:none"/>
        <span class="label wk_action" id="edit_link_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>">



        <p id="updatedprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red; position:relative; top:16px;">Updated</p>
        <br/>



 <button id="price_update_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" class="update" onclick="updateFieldPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" style="display:none" >
         <span><span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span></span>
         </button>
         <button id="price_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" style="display:none" >
         <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
         </button>                                                       
        </span>
```

**JS**

```
function showFieldPrice(product_id)
        {

            var qtyId='#price_'+ product_id;

            var editLink="#price_edit_link_"+ product_id;
            var valueprice="#valueprice_"+ product_id;
            var updateButton="#price_update_button_"+ product_id;
            var resetButton="#price_reset_button_"+ product_id;

            $wk_jq(qtyId).show();
            $wk_jq(valueprice).hide();

            $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).show();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).prop('disabled', false);//just in case
            $wk_jq(resetButton).show();

            return false;


        }

function updateFieldPrice(product_id)
{
var priceId = '#price_'+ product_id;
var valueId = '#valueprice_'+ product_id;
var updatedqty = '#updatedprice_'+ product_id;


var editLink = "#price_edit_link_"+ product_id;
var updateButton = "#price_update_button_"+ product_id;
var resetButton = "#price_reset_button_"+ product_id;
var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldPrice/')?>';

$wk_jq(priceId).toggle()

$wk_jq(editLink).hide();
$wk_jq(updateButton).hide();
$wk_jq(resetButton).hide();

$price = $wk_jq(priceId).val();
jQuery(valueId).html($price);
jQuery(valueId).show();
hideReset(product_id);

new Ajax.Request(url, {
method: 'post',
parameters: {id: product_id, price: $price},
onComplete: function (transport) {
//alert(transport.responseText);



jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut();

$updateButton.prop('disabled', false);


// $wk_jq(priceId).setValue($price);


jQuery(priceId).val($price);
// $wk_jq(priceId).setValue($price);



}
});
}
```

Comment: sorry don't get you what you want if the user click on text it will show the edit?

Comment: without clicking only it should be editable , means can you please click here : https://sellercentral.amazon.in/

Comment: than click on Inventory >  "Manage Inventory" you can see "Available " column there.

Comment: below you can see textfield, without clicking only we can edit there.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code..

```
<td>
    <span class="label pro_status">
            <?php //echo $products->getPrice(); ?>                              




            <input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "price_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" "name = "price" value = "<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" onchange="updateFieldPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>')" style = ""/>




            <p id="updatedprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red; position:relative; top:16px;">Updated</p>
            <br/>




            </span> </td>


function updateFieldPrice(product_id)
    {
    var priceId = '#price_'+ product_id;

    var updatedqty = '#updatedprice_'+ product_id;



    var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldPrice/')?>';





    $price = $wk_jq(priceId).val();



    new Ajax.Request(url, {
    method: 'post',
    parameters: {id: product_id, price: $price},
    onComplete: function (transport) {
    //alert(transport.responseText);



    jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut();








    }
    });
    }
```

Comment: its showing 2 text fields now : can you please check here :

http://2.kidsdial.com/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/

email : kidsdial2@gmail.com

pw : 123456

Comment: here is 1 code backup your file and add these only.

Comment: i removed all code and added only 2 lines gave by you. now please check  : http://2.kidsdial.com/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/ once we click on update button its blank.

Comment: add these js function too `updateFieldPrice` in question

Comment: please check the question

Comment: i  updated the quantity, it showing updated, once we refresh the page, it showing old price

Comment: please check the link now.

Comment: kindly update the js code and check the design problem

Comment: move back to file and place only these two.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97945/discussion-between-profile-101-and-qaisar-satti).

Comment: updated the html place it there deisgn will be fixed

Comment: please check here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34676207/magento-save-all-textfields-by-clicking-one-update-button-quantity-not-working and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34676462/display-cancel-button-only-when-we-edit-the-value-inside-textfield