# magento save all Textfields by clicking one Update Button - Quantity not working

Tags: php, magento

we are using following code to edit the **price , quantity** textfields for all products by clicking on one button. Price is working fine. **Quantity is not working**

**Phtml code for Price**

```
<input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "price_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name= "price[]" value = "<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" style = ""/>

<input type="hidden" name="curr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" id="curr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" value="<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" />

<p id="updatedprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red; position:relative; top:16px;">Updated</p>
<br/>

<button id="price_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>','<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>'); return false;">

<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
</button>
</span>
```

**Phtml code for QTY**

```
<?php
$selllermpassignproduct=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getAssignProDetails($products->getId());
//Zend_Debug::dump($selllermpassignproduct,null,true);
$stock_item=Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($products->getId());

$SellerQty=isset($selllermpassignproduct['sellerqty'])?$selllermpassignproduct['sellerqty']:$stock_item->getQty();
$assignqty=isset($selllermpassignproduct['assignqty'])?$selllermpassignproduct['assignqty']:0;
?>


<input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "qty_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name = "stock" value = "<?php echo (int) $SellerQty; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo (int) $SellerQty; ?>" id="currqty_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>">


<p id="updatedqty_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red; position:relative; top:16px;">Updated</p>
<br/>


<button id="reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideReset('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;"  >
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
</button>
```

**code to update price and quantity for all products by clicking one button**

**controller.php**

```
 public function massupdatesellerproAction(){
    if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
        if(!$this->_validateFormKey()){
             $this->_redirect('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/');
        }
        $ids= $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_mass_update');
        $price= $this->getRequest()->getParam('price');
        $qty = $this->getRequest()->getParam('qty');
        foreach ($ids as $key => $value) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($value);
    $product->setPrice($price[$key]);   // price
    $product->setQty($qty[$key]);       //qty



    $product->save();
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess( Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Products has been sucessfully deleted from your account'));
        $this->_redirect('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/');


    }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "qty_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name = "stock" value = "<?php echo (int) $SellerQty; ?>" />
```

you have calling the in name `qty` and your field name is `stock` change it to

```
<input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "qty_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name = "qty[]" value = "<?php echo (int) $SellerQty; ?>" />
```

Comment: stilll the same issue

Comment: refresh cache after it

Comment: try `print_r($qty);` and check you getting vlaues?

Comment: yes, i am getting quantity, because when i try to update through other button, its working

please check   http://prntscr.com/9ni87h "update" is working " save all" is not working

Comment: is price is updating?

Comment: check there not repetitive name for qty?

Comment: pls visit [site](http://sb1.collagekingapp.com/) and tell me what language is displaying for you in top

Comment: usa language displaying

Comment: please check now and tell me

Comment: please try in private window or other browser.