# Display cancel button only when we edit the value inside textfield

Tags: javascript, php, magento

we are using following code for display Price textfield.  we will edit the value and click on update button. if we missly type some numbers in textfields we will click on cancel button ,it will show the original value.

Now cancel button is displaying below text field. what i want is

1)cancel button should display only when we type the updated quantity inside textfield.

2)Once we click on update button , again "cancel" button should hide.

[image]

**Phtml**

```
<input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "price_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name= "price[]" value = "<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" style = ""/>

<input type="hidden" name="curr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" id="curr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" value="<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" />

<p id="updatedprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red; position:relative; top:16px;">Updated</p>
<br/>

<button id="price_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>','<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>'); return false;">

<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
function hideResetPrice(product_id,priceold) { 

var qtyId='#price_'+ product_id; 
var currprice='#curr_'+ product_id; 
var editLink="#price_edit_link_"+ product_id; 
var updateButton="#price_update_button_"+ product_id; 
var valueprice="#valueprice_"+ product_id; 
var resetButton="#price_reset_button_"+ product_id; 


$wk_jq(valueprice).show(); 
$wk_jq(qtyId).val( $wk_jq(currprice).val()); 
$wk_jq(editLink).show(); 

}



function showFieldPrice(product_id)
        {

            var qtyId='#price_'+ product_id;

            var editLink="#price_edit_link_"+ product_id;
            var valueprice="#valueprice_"+ product_id;
            var updateButton="#price_update_button_"+ product_id;
            var resetButton="#price_reset_button_"+ product_id;

            $wk_jq(qtyId).show();
            $wk_jq(valueprice).hide();

            $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).show();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).prop('disabled', false);//just in case
            $wk_jq(resetButton).show();

            return false;


        }   

        </script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask your question has formatting issues. you should make it easy to read so people could help you without much effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using `jQuery`. You have to check current value with hidden value. if they are equal then there is no need to show cancel button otherwise you are editing the value. and your code should be like

```
<input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "price_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>"  name= "price[]" value = "<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" style = ""/>

<input type="hidden" class="test_class" name="curr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" id="curr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" value="<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" />

<p id="updatedprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red; position:relative; top:16px;">Updated</p>
<br/>

<button id="price_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>','<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>'); return false;">

    <span><span class="cancle_button" style="display: none;"><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
</button>
```

JS

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ama1').keyup(function(){
        var hid_val = $('.test_class').val();
        var cur_val = $(this).val();
        if(hid_val != cur_val){
            $('.cancle_button').show();
        }else{
            $('.cancle_button').hide();
        }
    })
})
</script>
```

check [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/urfusion/p0efaj0g/)

Comment: `$('.cancle_button').toggle(hid_val != cur_val)`

Comment: @urfusion , now value inside textfield is not showing.

Comment: @alex  i tried above answer, but its hiding the valuue inside textfield

Comment: @BabyinCoding : remove `onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)"` and check

Comment: still its invisible- both values and cancel button

Comment: I am just getting values by jquery and hiding cancel button. there is nothing to with the input field hiding. check your browser console for errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100148/discussion-between-baby-in-coding-and-urfusion).

Comment: please help me here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35628694/quantity-is-not-updating-in-magento-site/35645699#35645699

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery, I post example with snippets, you can try this in your code.

I hope this will help you,

```js
 var original = $('.input').val(); // store original value
$('.cancel').hide();
$('.updates').hide();

$('.input').keyup(function(){  
  var cur_val = $(this).val();  
  if(original != cur_val){
     $('.cancel').show();
     $('.updates').show();
  }else{
      $('.cancel').hide();
      $('.updates').hide();
  }
});

$('.cancel').on('click',function(){
  $('.input').val(original);
  $(this).hide();
  $('.updates').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input" value="25.00">
<span class="updates" style="color:red;">Updated</span>
<button class="cancel">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: please post valid html, you posted the extra span, check that and also check you got a value from `$product` object

Comment: Please check my updated answer, now you just integrate your `$product` values, thats all.

Comment: please help me here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35628694/quantity-is-not-updating-in-magento-site/35645699#35645699